# LSTM encoder model input

Tags: lstm, encoder, anomaly-detection

When I want to use the LSTM-encoder model for anomaly detection, can I input both normal data and anomaly data while training the LSTM-encoder model? Or is only the normal data needed to be used for training?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the anomaly detection problem formulation, it is a one-class (normal class). So, to the extent possible, the training data

Note that it is still desirable to have labeled instances of both classes in the validation and test sets - so that one can do performance evaluation using precision/recall et.c.

Any presence of the anomaly class is considered a contamination of the training data (undesirable). But in some cases it is unavoidable, and a small amount can still lead to an OK anomaly detection model. But one can consider using the anomaly detection input as a scoring mechanism for labling more of the data - to clean the training set.